# Faster to run Python in app or import CSV

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I've got a website using Plotly / Dash (so Flask web framework) that imports CSV files from a variety of sources and presents the results as charts / data.

See here: https://app.qiinsights.com/apps/payments

What is a faster / more efficient / more scalable method:

1. import a raw CSV file and do all the python processing in the app (to produce multiple dataframes for use in charts and tables) (more processing in app)

or

2. do all the python processing offline and import multiple csv files that are ready to go (more downloads in app)

Comment: If you do all the processing offline and just read the processed files in your web app, it would always be more efficient and faster. You could set up a separate processing pipeline for your csv files which updates a database somewhere. The web app can read directly off of that database so everytime it reads it will be the 'latest' version.

Comment: The reason is quite obvious : if you process the files every time on the app, it would take n*(server resources) if n people are viewing the app, which will easily make the server unresponsive and loaded. (not scalable at all). However if you provide processed csvs the server will just have to 'serve' the files, a much less demanding operation (depending on your processing)

Comment: So is potentially longer download time of the csvs a better outcome because it isn't using server resources?

Comment: How many CSVs do you have?

Comment: each page is 1-3, generally small files. If i pre-process the data it would be 3-10 per page

Comment: According to the link you sent, you had about 10 pages, and each had 3-10 CSVs. You could store the CSVs on the server itself and just load one when needed directly from the server without the client needing to download any CSVs. Note you would need a bit of storage (since there are about < 100 CSVs in total. I don't believe that those CSVs would be larger than a few tens of kBs (how big are they on avg?). So, 10 kB * 100 = 1000 kB ~ 1MB (so pretty minimal storage reqs)

Comment: Most aren't big - although some are about 1MB - but still small. I have them hosted on AWS - does having them on the server reduce the load time? I understand the user doesn't download the CSV, so if they are on the server they just need to be processed, not downloaded in any way? Is that different to AWS hosting?

Comment: If the files are locally available to the server, it will definitely reduce load times and save on the bandwidth (if that is a concern) since they won't be needed to be downloaded from AWS every time, you're correct. (I am assuming here the files are hosted on AWS separately right now, the server is hosted somewhere else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing more processing offline is better and using more csv is better. Otherwise you will have to compute on the server for each viewer each time. But I think the better way of doing this is to have a small built-in database. And you can store those processed csv values into the database. And on your app can pull the data from the database directly. And there are some databased specially design for storing those 'one time' and quick updated data.

I would recommend using [apache druid](https://druid.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping to start simple without a database but I'll look into it.

Comment: If you took a look at druid, you can upload a csv into a table automatically.

Comment: do you have any documentation for that? Finding it hard to find

Comment: https://neontapir.github.io/professional/2017/02/10/ingest-csv-druid/